# AS3 undefined property stageVideos

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have an AS3 Mobile AIR project targeting iOS and Android. For some reason when I try to access stageVideos i.e. stage.stageVideos[0]...there is NO stageVideos property available on stage?? Very strange as I've done it before. My app is using Starling and Features UI framework, and my class is extending Screen. I'm fairly new to both frameworks but have been AS veteren. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some code? Also are you sure you are using Stage and not Stage3D?

Comment: Are you targeting the right flash/air version?

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out. The flash display stage is available in Starling.current.nativeStage.stageVideos[0]; But you need to hide the Starling.current.stage3D FIRST or it will not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Should be hardware problem. When StageVideo is not available on particular device stage.stageVideos property is empty, so to make sure you should make check like this.

```
var stageVideo:StageVideo;

if ( stage.stageVideos.length >= 1 ) {
    stageVideo = stage.stageVideos[0];
}
```

or register  StageVideoAvailabilityEvent on stage

```
stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, stageVideoChange);

private function stageVideoChange(e:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent):void
{
    if(e.availability == AVAILABLE)
    {
         // (stage.stageVideos.length >= 1) is TRUE so we can use stageVideo[0]
    }
    else
    {
         // StageVideo become unavailable for example after going from fullscreen 
         // back to wmode=normal, wmode=opaque, or wmode=transparent
    }
}
```

Of course second approach is more acceptable because you are notified every time StageVideo becomes available or negative. Note if stage video is available at the moment of registering Listener on StageVideoAvailabilityEvent then listener function (stageVideoChange) is called immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Starling runs on Stage3D on TOP of the actual flash display stage. So in order to do this, you need to hide the Starling Stage3D first:

```
Starling.current.stage3D.visible = false
```

Then you can access and show...etc stageVideos and add to the flash display stage:

```
_stageVideo = Starling.current.nativeStage.stageVideos[0];
```

So basically, the native flash display stage is on the Starling.current.nativeStage property, however, can not be visible unless you first hide the Starling.current.stage3D FIRST.

Thanks for the responses! Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem.